# Showing a function is measurable

Tags: real-analysis

> *Let $\chi_{E}(x)$ and $\chi_{F}(x)$ be the characteristic functions of $E$ and $F$, where $E$ and $F$ are measurable sets and $E \cup F = \mathbb{R^n}$. Prove by definition that $f(x) = 6\chi_{E}(x) - 5\chi_{F}(x)$ is measurable.*

My solution is:

*First we show that $a+b$ is measurable for any measurable functions $a$ and $b$. Since $b$ is measurable, we have the set $\{b(x) \gt \alpha\}$ is measurable $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R^n}$. Hence $\{-b(x) \gt \alpha\}$ = $\{b(x) \lt -\alpha\}$ is measurable for all $\alpha$ and so -b is measurable. Since $\{\beta - b(x) \gt \alpha\}$ = $\{b(x) \gt \alpha - \beta\}$ is measurable $\forall\alpha$ since $\alpha - \beta \in \mathbb{R^n}$, we have that $\beta - b(x)$ is measurable for any $\beta$. Thus, since $\{a(x) + b(x) \gt \alpha\}$ = $\{a(x) \gt \alpha - b(x)\}$ which is measurable for any $\alpha$ since $\alpha - b(x)$ is measurable, we have $a+b$ is measurable.*

*Since $\chi_{E}(x)$ and $\chi_{F}(x)$ are characteristic functions, we know they are measurable. Hence, $\{ \chi_{E}(x) \gt \alpha \}$ and $\{ \chi_{F}(x) \gt \alpha \}$ are measurable $\forall\alpha$. Since $\{ 6\chi_{E}(x) \gt \alpha \}$
= $\{ \chi_{E}(x) \gt \frac{\alpha}{6} \}$ where $\frac{\alpha}{6} \in \mathbb{R^n}$, we have $6\chi_{E}(x)$ is measurable. Similarly, $-5\chi_{E}(x)$ is measurable.*

*Thus, $f(x) = 6\chi_{E}(x) - 5\chi_{F}(x)$ is measurable.*

I never used the fact that $E \cup F = \mathbb{R^n}$, is what I've done still correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it asks you to prove it by definition, it is probably expected that you show $f^{-1}(B)$ is Borel-measurable for any Borel-measurable set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Note that since $E \cup F = \mathbb{R}^n$, we have the disjoint union

$$\mathbb{R}^n = (E \setminus F) \cup (E \cap F) \cup (F \setminus E)$$

Thus we have

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
6,  & \text{if $x \in E \setminus F$} \\
1, & \text{if $x \in E \cap F$} \\
-5& \text{if $x \in F \setminus E$} \\
\end{cases}$$

So

$$f^{-1}(B) = \begin{cases}
E \setminus F,  & \text{if $B \cap \{6,1,-5\} = \{6\}$} \\
E, & \text{if $B \cap \{6,1,-5\} = \{6,1\}$} \\
(E \setminus F) \cup (F \setminus E)& \text{if $B \cap \{6,1,-5\} = \{6,-5\}$} \\
\mathbb{R}^n, & \text{if $B \cap \{6,1,-5\} = \{6,1,-5\}$} \\
E \cap F & \text{if $B \cap \{6,1,-5\} = \{1\}$} \\
F, & \text{if $B \cap \{6,1,-5\} = \{1,-5\}$} \\
F \setminus E& \text{if $B \cap \{6,1,-5\} = \{-5\}$} \\
\emptyset& \text{if $B \cap \{6,1,-5\} = \emptyset$} \\
\end{cases}$$

All the possible preimages are Borel-measurable so $f^{-1}(B)$ must be Borel-measurable.

We conclude that $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a really cool way to do this. I've never seen something like this though, our definition for a measurable set was just that {f>a} is measurable for every constant a. Thanks for the cool solution though.

Comment: @ben Well, $\{f > a\} = f^{-1}(\langle a, +\infty\rangle)$ so you can still use this argument.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand-thank you very much for your help, I never would have thought of doing it this way but it's much more straightforward. Thank you for all your help!